# How to determine rise time of a signal from its noisy background timeseries?

Tags: time-series, signal-detection, noise

[image]I have temperature vs. time data from a thermometer. The data was recorded using a DAQ system, has a stable background level, and some random noise. At a certain time, the temperature begins to rise above the background, but still has the random noise. If there a method is statistics to determine at what time the temperature begins to rise, and to define a temperature 'threshold' based on the background signal? Exceeding this threshold would be the 'rise' time.

The data used the plot the curve can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6OcDHL7PW9Db0hMWTVsNmJBak0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You could fit an additive (spline) model to characterise the mean or level of the series over time and then compute the first derivative of the spline and it's confidence interval and look where the confidence interval on the derivative no longer includes zero. You'd need to fit the model accounting for potential temporal autocorrelation among the residuals also.

Comment: Can you make the data available?

Comment: @AlexeyGrigorev, I've added a link to the data.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, I fitted a spline to the data and calculated piecewise derivatives. How do I calculate the confidence intervals on these derivatives? I have very little statistics background, so need some more help.

Comment: @cryonole I have a couple of posts assuming the use of the **mgcv** package in R: http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2014/05/15/identifying-periods-of-change-with-gams/ and http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2014/06/16/simultaneous-confidence-intervals-for-derivatives/